# what is a simple parametric VaR approach that can be used to compare with ISDA SIMM results?

Tags: value-at-risk, isda-simm

i am looking for a simple parametric VaR approach that includes vega and/or gamma.
i am not sure if to choose a non symmetric distribution for the pnl, what would people use, perhaps some shifted lognormal (shifted so it's mean is zero) ? , or to just choose normal.  i think isda simm uses normal , but then, how do they achieve that the IM for each party is different ?

also if anyone has any links to maths that show the derivation for the isda simm formulas, or can offer a simple explanation of them here that would be great to see!

Comment: ISDA‘s SIMM is based off a Delta-Gamma risk calculation. 1) this gives you differential margin requirements for long/short options portfolios. 2) you could try to get your parametric model from  your portfolios deltas, Gammas, and risk factor covariance matrix. ISDA had some of their documentation freely available at early model stages but these docs seem (?) to have been removed at some point.

Comment: This could be one starting point: https://qftc.com.mx/img/The%20practice%20of%20Delta%E2%80%93Gamma%20VaR%20Implementing.pdf

Comment: .. and of course this answer here https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/52945/31263